# managing web assembly versioning and single dll releases

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, version

My company release several web sites as part of our release procedure. Generally this is all done at a point in time agreed by everyone, etc.

We strongly version our dll's based on our subversion SVN revision number. So:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.22.0.13724")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.22.0.13724")]
```

where the dll version is MajorVersion.release.minorversion.SVNRevision number.

All fine and nicely tracable.

Occasionally we have to do emergency releases out side of our main release schedule. To minimise impact we generally release a single dll.

We've discovered that if we change the version number then this breaks the site. Not sure why, I must admit but I'm presuming this is to do with IIS or something?!

Were now implementing a system where were going to read and report the version reflected out of the dll's. (Don't worry about this we've got something in place to do this using singletons and reflection).

So my question is: is there a way to update a single dll's version number without breaking a build running through IIS6? How does IIS reference the dll's it needs and what does this have to do with the version of that dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS shouldn't have anything to do with it.  All of the other assemblies in the application are referencing a certain DLL and if you just drop in a new DLL with a new version number, those DLLs that are referencing the old DLL will now break.  IIS just compiles everything together for you.  But if Assembly A is looking for Assembly B, V1 and you replace Assembvly B, V2, assembly A's reference is now invalid.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought but my colleague assures me he's tried this and it breaks the build. I'll have to try it myself an see what happens.